# Python - Fetching data from API

Tags: python, api, pagerduty

I have the below code that fetches data from a API. This works fine, however I see that it only returns back 25 rows. I am trying to see how could I extract all of the data from the API call and not limit to 25

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


API_KEY = API_KEY



url = 'https://api.pagerduty.com/incidents/'
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2',
    'Authorization': 'Token token={token}'.format(token=API_KEY)}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = r.content
data_dict = json.loads(data)
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict['incidents'])
```

Comment: have you tried using r.json() instead od data = r.content -> json.loads(data)? if call was successful, requests will always have the full response (unless the API returned partial data)

Answer (score 3):

That is due to pagination in the API response. The call defaults to return 25 incidents. If you pass a `limit` parameter, you can get more, but only up to 100. If you loop until `more` is false and increment the offset each call you can get all the incidents.

See here [API Reference for `limit`](https://v2.developer.pagerduty.com/v2/docs/pagination)

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation [here](https://v2.developer.pagerduty.com/docs/pagination).

You can pass the query parameter for example

```
url = 'https://api.pagerduty.com/incidents?limit=50'
```

The maximum limit as per docs is 100 so you will have to send multiple GET requests. If there are thousands of records make sure your python script send GET request at specific time interval because of rate-limiting else will through Too Many Requests error.